# Altman Z-Score model for PD calculation

Tags: risk, risk-models, credit, default-probability, credit-ratings

I am approaching you with one important for me question.

I have a task to calculate probability of default for our clients. I used an Altman Z-Score model to calculate the Z-Scores for each client.

Question N 1: Could you advise me how can I transform this Z-score to Probability of Default rate(%)?

The second, I am not fully satisfied with the results of Altman model, because, for example, one of our clients has an internal risk class 5 (it means, that it is in a risky zone), but the Z-Score I calculate for this client is quite high, and vice versa.

Question N 2: Can I transform our internal risk classifications (1,2,3....8) to probability of default rate (%)? If I can, how? If it is possible, I will write on which criterias we define our internal risk classifications.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Part two of your question sounds a lot like this one which recently got closed: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32996/calculation-of-pd-rate.

Comment: I went through the link, but it is not answered.

Comment: My point was that posting a question that if that question is off topic then the second part of this one probably is as well. The overlap between the two is truly surprising.

Comment: Good catch @LocalVolatility

Comment: I just have two questions, and have a hope that I will receive a reasonable for me answer or an advice, I do not make comparisons with first part or second part of other topics. Now I want to know whether this link was an answer to my questions?

Comment: Now when I read the question in the link you sent, this is really the same question, but I don't understand what's the problem if the questions are alike.

Comment: @Garik Surely you must understand that there are an infinite number of possible transformations that apply to integers and convert them into a percentage. The question is too broad. A totally satisfying answer (from the info you give) would for instance be to define a pointwise correspondence between each integer and a fixed percentage rate like 1: 10%, ..., 5: 50%, 8: 80%. It's merely a model.